# Android applications obtain permission cannot run normally

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

Wrote a get contacts and contact phone number and then displayed in the small program, but after get permission in Android 6 cannot display the data, to restart the program to read properly. I think it should be there access out of the question, because after restart the authority need not ask when can read properly, and need the pop-up dialog asking while allowing access permissions but still can't show, but after the restart.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    ListView contactsView;
 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 
    List<String> contactsList = new ArrayList<String>();
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        contactsView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_view);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.
                simple_list_item_1, contactsList);
        contactsView.setAdapter(adapter);
        insertDummyContactWrapper();
    }
 
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
 
    private void insertDummyContactWrapper() {
        int hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
        readContacts();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission Granted
                    readContacts();
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "READ_CONTACTS Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
 
    public void readContacts() {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.
                        CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.
                        CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                contactsList.add(displayName + "\n" + number);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your code is working! what issue you are faceing. I have check your code in nexus 5 with 6.0

Comment: After the first asked whether to grant permissions, click allow doesn't read data, to restart the program.

Comment: i have tried it. give permission at first time it read data. have you test code in device?

Comment: i test code in Genymotion.

Comment: try in real device its working